# Is XFBML extension supported?

Tags: xfbml, facebook-javascript-sdk

Back when the JavaScript SDK was initially released, the documentation included an extension model for XFBML, specifically the FB.XFBML.registerTag method appeared to be "public". Now that Facebook is working on restricting access to internal functions in the SDK, it would be good to know whether there's still support for the use of extension functions like FB.XFBML.registerTag and FB.subclass.

More specifically, where is the documentation for these?